# <router-outlet> from up level component. Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have `<mat-sidenav-container>`  And I do navigation with `<mat-sidenav>` and `<routeroutlet>` in `<mat-sidenav-content>`

```
<mat-sidenav-content class="body-sidenav">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

It is work good

My router

```
{
path: 'article-section',
component: AllSectionComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: 'article-section/:id',
    component: ArticleComponent,
  },
]
```

},

I need this template

[image]

As I undestood I need next `<routeroutlet>` in AllSectionComponent

such this

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="center-folder">
 <div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let item of articleSection"
   style="width: 100px; margin-right:10px; margin-left: 10px; margin- 
   bottom: 10px;">
    <img class="img-section" src="assets/images/docimgaes/section.png" /> 
    <br>
    <a [routerLink]="['/article-section', 1]">
      <div class="name-section">{{item.name}}</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

But with this case I open component of object in the head of AllSectionComponent :). And I have two html. I need open normally with  `<routeroutlet>` which is in `<mat-sidenav-content>`. Do I need name routeroutlet or maybe there are more comfortable decisions???

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question from how you wrote it, but look at this this way: In your sidenav you only have elements with [routerLink] that will declare which component you want to show, and router-outlet will render that component. So, in sidenav only links, in some other component (where AllSectionComponent should render), put router-outlet.

Comment: Yes. In side nav only links. In right side I render component wich I chose. Component open and I see many object in it. All this oject have a link to details of themself. I need to open in my <mat-sidenav-content> details of objects. I did such you said. You can see it in the question. I put router-outlet there and after this I have two html page in one :)  1. whis is rendered by new router-outlet whis you advise to put. 2. html of AllSectionComponent which I open in side nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need it to remake my router.

from this

My router from this

```
    {
      path: 'article-section',
       component: AllSectionComponent,
       children: [
            {
          path: 'article-section/:id',
          component: ArticleComponent,
        },
       ]
```

To this

```
       {
        path: 'article-section',
        component: AllSectionComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'article-section/:id',
        component: ArticleComponent,
      },
```